# Can I site-host a bintray instance?

Tags: bintray

I would like to have a corporate deployment mechanism for making releases from Bamboo --> Artifactory --> Bintray, with approvals at each step.  But, I still want the final Bintray instance to exist within our corporate domain, and off the web.
From [Jfrog's website](https://bintray.com/account/pricing?tab=account&type=pricing), it seems that there is not a site-hosted version available. Can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bintray is not available as an on premise installation - yet... :)

(PS. I'm with JFrog)